# how to install jrjohansson's python wavefunction package?

Tags: python

I have installed QuTip at my CentOS 6.5.

Now I try to run this code

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jrjohansson/wavefunction/blob/master/Wavefunction-Phase-Qubit-Current-Biased.ipynb

I copy the above codes

```
from scipy import *
from scipy import optimize

from wavefunction import *
from wavefunction.wavefunction1d import *
....
```

but have some error when running

```
 ImportError: No module named 'wavefunction'
```

Then I use

```
conda install wavefunction
pip install wavefunction
```

still don't work

```
No matching distribution found for wavefunction
Package not found
```

Please help me to resolve this issue about the install of the python 'wavefunction' package

Answer (score 1):

Seems like he hasnt uploaded it to conda or pypi. In such cases, you can install it with git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/jrjohansson/wavefunction.git#egg=wavefunction
```